# c++ argv contains unknown arguments

Tags: c++, debugging, argv

While debugging my program, I saw in the debugger that argv contains arguments that I didn't wrote.
First argument is my path to executable but then it contains a lot of arguments, the most of them not even reachable.

[image: argv]

As you can see, I'm using CLion and I didn't take any argument while running my program. What can it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must look at variable `argc` for the count of valid arguments.

You can keep looking further down the array at `argv[1000000]`, but that does not mean there is anything useful there.

Looking at any element beyond `argv[argc-1]` is meaningless.  Do not do it.

In your case, I'm confident that `argc == 1`, and the only valid argument is `argv[0]`, which is the name of your program, `serverRun.exe`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's strange that CLion try to look at those variables, thought it was a bad move from myself

Comment: Should say "beyond `argv[argc]`".  That one is defined to be null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The content you see should not be used. It is very likely utilized by the debugger to track unwanted behaviors such as overflows. The addresses contain *Magic debug values*.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29):

> **Magic debug values** are specific values written to memory during
> allocation or deallocation, so that it will later be possible to tell
> whether or not they have become corrupted, and to make it obvious when
> values taken from uninitialized memory are being used. Memory is
> usually viewed in hexadecimal, so memorable repeating or hexspeak
> values are common.
>
> Numerically odd values may be preferred so that
> processors without byte addressing will fault when attempting to use
> them as pointers (which must fall at even addresses). Values should be
> chosen that are away from likely addresses (the program code, static
> data, heap data, or the stack).

For instance:

**ABABABAB**: *Used by Microsoft's debug HeapAlloc() to mark "no man's land" guard bytes after allocated heap memory.*

**FEEEFEEE**:   *"Fee fee", Used by Microsoft's debug HeapFree() to mark freed heap memory. Some nearby internal bookkeeping values may have the high word set to FEEE as well.*

...